# Implement Strassen's algorithm

Tags: code-golf, matrix

[Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) was the first method of matrix multiplication in subcubic time complexity, namely `O(n**log2(7))` for a pair of `n*n` matrices (assuming the numbers therein are large enough that their `O(n*log2(n))` exact multiplication has become the constraint on your performance, and any nested structures and function calls are negligible in comparison).

For a `2*2` matrix, it is defined as

```python
lambda a,b: (lambda a,b,c,d,e,f,g: (a+d-e+g,c+e,b+d,a-b+c+f))((a[0]+a[3])*(b[0]+b[3]),(a[2]+a[3])*b[0],a[0]*(b[1]-b[3]),a[3]*(b[2]-b[0]),(a[0]+a[1])*b[3],(a[2]-a[0])*(b[0]+b[1]),(a[1]-a[3])*(b[2]+b[3]))
```

And for larger square ones, as splitting them into quarters and then calling this but with numbers' addition, negation and multiplication methods substituted for matrices' (notably using itself for the latter, its seven self-calls per doubling of the width and height being the reason for the exponent).

For simplicity (so you won't need to deal with implementing standard matrix multiplication and subdividing into Strassen-able ones), your inputs will be two `2**n*2**n` matrices of integers, represented as length-`2**(2*n)` tuples (or lists or your language's equivalent), encoded with elements in reading order, and you will return another such tuple. For instance, when inputted with these two

```python
(5,2,0,0,
 4,0,5,2,
 3,4,5,0,
 3,1,4,2)

(7,4,5,3,
 4,0,2,7,
 1,4,1,1,
 0,5,3,5)
```

, it should return

```python
(43,20,29,29,
 33,46,31,27,
 42,32,28,42,
 29,38,27,30)
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) I've closed this question as it is missing an objective scoring criteria. For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66833) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main

Comment: The requirement that answers implement this specific algorithm is unobservable - also see [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23971/100664)

Comment: I would add [tag:restricted-complexity]

Comment: How order the length-2**(2*n) tuples ?

Comment: @emanresuA they could equivalently ask for a matrix multiplication algorithm with the stated time complexity. I am not sure there is more than one.

Comment: Please add some testcases

Comment: @emanresu, I don't know whether there's more than one either, but Strassen's could equivalently have its inputs swapped (and elements of which transposed) in the computation of the constants (and then retransposed for the output), but I don't know what you mean by unobservable when your link says "unless you pick _your algorithm and the problem_ very carefully," and there exists a code golf task for general matrix multiplication (that can be solved with the schoolbook algorithm) also if you would like.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has an unobservable requirement, as mentioned by Mousetail.

Comment: How so? A general "multiply two matrices" question could be solved by a much easier method (and already exists in an existing challenge), should the condition instead be that it must run in time complexity less than or equal to `O(n**lg(7))` (where multiplication of the inputs takes asymptotic to 100% of the total time), or more specifically in `n**lg(7)` multiplications? The algorithm is well-defined, it can be observed whether an answer abides by it. Should I state that other algorithms based on coinciding factorisations are also acceptable? I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## One-line Python (1027 bytes)

(explained in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DroneBetter/b184fbff57077de3ec720d0a0add9ff2), would be greatly reducible if you were to be less pedantic about it all being one line)

```python
from functools import reduce
from math import isqrt
from random import random
lap=(lambda f,*a: list(map(f,*a)))
strassen=(lambda a,b: tuple((lambda f: f(a,b) if len(a)==4 else (lambda m: (lambda m,d: ((m[y*2+x][d*j+i] for y in range(2) for j in range(d) for x in range(2) for i in range(d))))(m,isqrt(len(m[0]))))(f(*(map((lambda m: (lambda m,d: tuple((tuple((m[i*d+j] for i in range(d//2*y,d//(2-y)) for j in range(d//2*x,d//(2-x)))) for y in range(2) for x in range(2))))(m,isqrt(len(m)))),(a,b))))))((lambda a,b: (lambda s,n,o,m: (lambda a,b,c,d,e,f,g: lap(s,((a,d,n(e),g),(c,e),(b,d),(a,n(b),c,f))))(*map(m,*map(lambda x: map(o,x),(((a[0],a[3]),(a[2],a[3]),(a[0],),(a[3],),(a[0],a[1]),(a[2],n(a[0])),(a[1],n(a[3]))),((b[0],b[3]),(b[0],),(b[1],n(b[3])),(b[2],n(b[0])),(b[3],),(b[0],b[1]),(b[2],b[3])))))))(*((sum,int.__neg__,sum,int.__mul__) if type(a[0])==int else ((lambda x: reduce(lambda a,b: lap(int.__add__,a,b),x)),(lambda x: map(int.__neg__,x)),(lambda t: t[0] if len(t)==1 else lap(int.__add__,*t)),strassen)))))))
```